# jQuery Validate Plugin overwrite my select onChange postback

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, sharepoint

I'm creating this form (.net) where i have a select with a postback, that will trigger a action depending on which option i select. I'm trying to use the jQuery Validate Plugin ([plugin website](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)) to validate my form.

My problem is, when i validate the form, and my select is marked as invalid, the validation plugin overwrite it's onChange method to make it unmark when i change the value, the thing is that it's deleting my __dopostback from the onchange, making  the form 'useless'.

Is there a way to the plugin validate my selects without deleting my postback action from the onchange?

Comment: It's not deleting it...it's stopping your `<form>` from submitting because it's invalid, which is it's job :)  You need to exclude that control from the validation or add an exception...or manually validate when you want to, e.g. do you have a single submit button?  You can validate *only* when it's clicked instead of on the form's `submit` event, if that works.

Comment: Nick, my submit button is calling a JS function in which i have all the form validation, it'll only submit the form when i want to (return true). I tried excluding the select field from the validations, but it still not doing the postback after i validate.

I have now the select and a textbox, if the textbox gets flagged as invalid (empty) by the jQuery validate, and i make it valid (type something in it), the select still not doing the postback when i select something. 

I'm kinda new to all this, so, sorry if this is obvious and i don't get it hehe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but I had a similar situation and was able to resolve it like this. Just thought I'd post it just in case someone else found there way here. I'm using jQuery Validation Plugin 1.9.0:

```
$('#aspnetForm').validate({
    errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
    wrapper: "li"
});

$("input[id$='myButton']").click(function () {
     SetRules();
     if ($('#aspnetForm').valid()) {
          // form passed validation

     } else {
          $('#aspnetForm').resetForm();
          return false;
     }
});

function SetRules(){
     $("select[id$='myDropDown']").rules("remove");
     $("select[id$='myDropDown']").rules("add", {required:true});
}
```

My validator is set up so errors display together in one designated div.  When I click the button, the validation fires and displays all the elements in that div and marks the fields that are invalid, including the select (all choices are red), and when I change the selection my autopostback fires and the colors of the select change back to their old value (assuming the choice passed the validation).

I am pretty new at this plugin, so I can't explain it too well but my thought process was to try and get the form to validate and show the errors, and then reset the controls back to their original state while still keeping the error messages visible.  I was expecting to lose the red error highlighting, but somehow that retained while also bringing back the select's postback.

Also, I do not know if setting the rules in this manner contributed to this working or not; I had to set them like this for various reasons, the biggest one due to needing the selector for .NET's automatically generated IDs.

Comment: How embarrassing, my usage of resetForm() is actually incorrect... as it is in that example it throws a javascript error when it hits that line... which ironically produces the desired results!  That certainly explains why it didn't have the output I expected... but keeping this behavior in mind may be the trick however to achieving these results without errors.